# Is it possible to have two LocationListeners at the same time?

Tags: java, android, gps, location, android-gps

I'm trying to create a gps logging app, which displays the gps provider coordinates, and network provider coordinates if debug mode is turned on. However, I'm getting a lot of problems (gps coordinates not displaying, not returning any altitude etc.). I haven't found any mistakes in my code so far, so I started wondering whether this is because I have two different services running at the same time, which contain Locationlisteners with the usual public methods:

`public void onLocationChanged(final Location loc)`

Is this the problem? Is it even possible to have two location services running at the same time?

Comment: If you suspect the problem is caused by two concurrent services, just run one of them and turn off the other at a time to see if it works. If not, you might have some other problems in your code which you need to provide more info about.

Comment: @solosodium They are able to run separately.

Comment: Well, you might need to share the code for the two service. The callback function you mentioned is part of LocationListener, which by default can be multiple instances attached to LocationManager. So the problem must be elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks, that's all I needed to know.